# Unable to include a .cmake file in another .cmake file from subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have a third party .cmake file, that is used as a tool chain file, that I want to include in my own .cmake tool chain file. I want to do this so I can set some arguments and call some macros defined in the third party .cmake file.

My project setup looks like this:

```
MyProject
├── myFile.cmake
└── thirdparty
    └── otherProject
        └── otherFile.cmake
```

The `otherFile.cmake` is in the directory `/thirdparty/otherProject` relative to my project. So in my `myFile.cmake` I have among many things tried this:

```
include(otherFile.cmake)
```

and this

```
include(thirdparty/otherProject/otherFile.cmake)
```

and this

```
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/otherProject)
include(otherFile.cmake)
```

and this

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_FILE}/thirdparty/otherProject/otherFile.cmake")
```

and many more such as include_directory(), but I always get:

> include could not find load file

and I always do a clean build just to be sure.

I would think this is a simple task, but cmake continues to baffle me so I'm reaching out for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out eventually:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/thirdparty/otherProject/otherFile.cmake)
```